# Understanding privateness and scope of functions called as methods and as constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

Please consider the following code:

```
function Outer(){
  function Inner(){
    var private="something";
    this.method = function(){    
     //some code here    
   };
  }

 var inner = new Inner(); //Why does this line not throw an error?
 alert(inner.private); // not accessible here
 inner.method();//no errors here
}
```

I am unable to understand why method() call doesn't throw an error and the variable reference throws an error? I understand that variables have their scope only within the function in which they are declared? But what about the scope of functions ?

Comment: `new Inner` *should* throw an error. Can you create a JsFiddle demo of this actually working?

Comment: Well, now you have fixed the scoping issue and it works exactly as expected.

Comment: @deceze I want to understand the scope of functions that are called as methods and as constructors through this question. An answer would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing complicated about it and it has nothing to do with data types.

`new Inner()` creates a new object. You are assigning a property to that object in the constructor

```
this.method = function(){...};
```

On the other side, there is not such property `private`. You never do `this.private = ...;`. `private` is just a variable local to the `Inner` function.

Here is another example which is equivalent to your code but hopefully makes it clearer:

```
function createObject() {
    var someVariable = '42';
    var obj  = {};
    obj.foo = 'bar';
    return obj;
}

var myObject = createObject();
// works, since we assigned the property to the object
console.log(myObject.foo); 
// does not work, we never assigned such a property to the object
console.log(myObject.someVariable);
```

Inside `createObject` two variables are declared, `someVariable` and `obj`. `obj` is an object, we assign a property to it and return it from the function. `someVariable` has nothing to do with the object, but could be used for other purposes within the function.

Comment: Why would you use closure for private though? I don't see google closure library using it and many other libraries don't use it as JS doesn't seem to support privates. Using it in this manner will break prototype (none of your privates/closures will be available in prototype functions) or force you to declare object methods with the "this.someMethod=function(){" syntax. I guess it's a way to prove a point that JS support private variables but I don't see any practical use for it when you need to create multiple instances.

Comment: @HMR: I totally agree with you. I never use it either. It just makes things more complicated, IMO. I mean, information hiding with closures is totally fine, but together with constructor functions and instances and inheritance, it just gets messy.

Comment: Thanks, and +1 for getting those darn underscores in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The line var inner = new Inner() does throw an error as inner is not defined, it's only accessible within the body of the Outer function.

The inner.private is not accessible as a property of inner because it's a [closure variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Closures). So (new Inner()).private does not exist. (private seems to be a keyword in JS so I changed it to priv in sample code)

It is accessible within the Inner function body because code within the function body keeps a reference to closure variables.

```
  function Inner(){
    var priv="something";
    this.method = function(){//wrong, should declare as prototype
     console.log("private from within Inner function body:"
       ,priv)
    };
  }

var inner = new Inner();
console.log(inner.priv); //=undefined
inner.method();//=something
```

A function property of an object that will have many instances; like Inner can have many instances like: var a=new Inner(); var b = new Inner()... Should not be defined with this. You should use prototype instead.

When you use prototype you can't use private variables in the prototype functions because private (closure) variables are only accessible within the main function body. This is why many developers use `_private` or `private_` to indicate it's private since JavaScript does not have a good way to make members private without messing up the prototype.

```
function Inner(){
  var priv="private";//wrong
  this._priv="private"
}
Inner.prototype.method=function(){
  //cannot access priv
  console.log(this._priv);//no problem
}
```

There is maybe one case where you can use privates in this way and that is when there is only one instance of your object.

```
var Mediator=(function(){
  var events={};//private, other code can't mess this up
  return{
    addEvent:function(eventName){
      events[eventName]=(events[eventName])?
        events[eventName]:[];
    },
    addLisener:function(eventName,func){
      events[eventName].push(func);
      return events[eventName].length-1;
    }
    //more stuff like removeListener, trigger ...
  }
})()
```

You can read about prototype [in this basic example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711). You can run the code in Chrome or Firefox with firebug console. Press F12 to open it and paste the code from that link in the console. Then fiddle with it as you like and see if you get the expected output and understand prototyping in JS.